# multiple export default in react.js module

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using redux connect and and react-localization-redux in same application. Both are needed export default like below

**in react-localize-redux**

```
export default withLocalize(App);
```

**in {connect} react-redux**

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InvoiceAuditMenu)
```

How to pass both in one module.

Answer (score 1):

You can't export 2 things as **default**.

Use one as a **default export** & use other as a **named export**.

```
export const withLocalizeApp = withLocalize(App);
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InvoiceAuditMenu);
```

**OR**

```
export default withLocalize(App);
export const connectedInvoiceAuditMenu = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InvoiceAuditMenu);
```

Or you can **default export** an object containing both functions like

```
const obj = {
 withLocalize: withLocalize(App),
 connectedInvoiceAuditMenu: connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InvoiceAuditMenu)
}
```